# Intellij IDEA Community Edition 2021.3.1 isn't recognising spring classes

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I have started learning spring boot I am facing a problem with my IDE Intellij .
Problem :
Intellij IDEA Community Edition 2021.3.1 isn't recognising spring annotations.

What I have done: I have initialised a spring boot project using spring initializr opened it in Intellij.
Marked the src folder as sources root.
[Intellij Not recognising Spring Classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUcSD.jpg)
Is there anyone who can help me out

Comment: The comm edition doesn't support spring: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/#section=windows You can use VS code with the appr. extensions.

Comment: Most OSes allow you take take screenshots, there shouldn't be a need to take a photograph of your screen (e.g. Windows-key + Shift + S on Windows, Cmd + Shift + 3 (or 4) on macOS).

Comment: _"Marked the src folder as sources root."_ sounds like you didn't properly import it as a Maven project.

Answer (score 1):

right click pom.xml and click on mavan->>Reload Project.
Its should downloads all dependencies .

Answer (score 0):

There are few things which went wrong in your intellij idea and the configuration of your project. You can try one by one any of the below steps to correct the issue.

1. The build path is not set properly, Please check the links on setting the build path properly and the JDK used for the project.
2. Invalidate cache and restart your IDE.

[image: Invalidate cache and restart your IDE]

3. Delete .idea folder and restart your IDE.
   [image: Delete .idea folder]

Hope it Works.